# make_request and queue limits

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a linux kernel module that emulates a block device.

There are various calls that can be used to tell the block size to the kernel, so it aligns and sizes every request toward the driver accordingly. This is well documented in the "Linux Device Drives 3" book.

The book describes two methods of implementing a block device: using a "request" function, or using a "make_request" function.

It is not clear, whether the queue limit calls apply when using the minimalistic "make_request" approach (which is also the more efficient one if the underlying device is has really no benefit from sequential over random IO, which is the case with me).

I would really like to get the kernel to talk to me using 4K block sizes, but I see smaller bio-s hitting my make_request function.

My question is that should the blk_queue_limit_* affect the bio size when using make_request?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that the problem was with the order of blk_queue_logical_block_size and blk_queue_make_request. The later function sets every block limit value to it's default, the logical sector size being 512 bytes. I only found empirical evidence to the fact that make_request receives only logical_block_size * k sized bios, so I would really like to see the lines in the kernel that guarantees this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found enough evidence in the kernel code that if you use make_request, you'll get correctly sized and aligned bios.

The answer is:

You must call blk_queue_make_request first, because it sets queue limits to defaults. After this, set queue limits as you'd like.

It seems that every part of the kernel submitting bios are do check for validity, and it's up to the submitter to do these checks. I've found incomplete validation in submit_bio and generic_make_request. But as long as no one does tricks, it's fine.

Since it's a policy to submit correct bio's, but it's up to the submitter to take care, and no one in the middle does, I think I have to implement explicit checks and fail the wrong bio-s. Since it's a policy, it's fine to fail on violation, and since it's not enforced by the kernel, it's a good thing to do explicit checks.

If you want to read a bit more on the story, see http://tlfabian.blogspot.com/2012/01/linux-block-device-drivers-queue-and.html.